# Traceback in warning messages

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, warnings

When a warning happens, I want to know the stack (since the function that caused the warning might have been called from different places). How can I make the warning message include the traceback information?

For instance, if I am importing a site package and that package throws an ambiguous warning, I would like to know what part of my code triggered the warning.

I don't want to convert warnings to errors (there are many warnings, and I'm not planning to eliminate them - just understand what causes them).

(Python 3.5) (also applies to python 2.7)